# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] trying to inject $module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the modal service from angular bootstrap:

```
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

My app controller (**index.js**):

```
var app = angular.module('emaApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    // ...
}]);
```

However, I am not getting beyond this error message and I don't see what the problem is:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=emaApp&p1=Error%3A%…host%3A8080%2Fweb%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4759
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at g (angular.js:4720)
    at eb (angular.js:4642)
    at c (angular.js:1838)
    at Mc (angular.js:1859)
    at pe (angular.js:1744)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:32977)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: @VinodLouis I don't know, [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) it says `ui.bootstrap.modal`.

Comment: Sure it's not `$uibModal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the modal inject the `$uibModal`

Your controller would then be:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If I go with `$uibModal` it works with `ui-bootstrap.js` as well

Comment: OK great, Then they included that in the core ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You've got to load this script:

```
<script src="..path_to_script../ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried with `<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>` but it's the same result. Interestingly it works with `$uibModal` like @Ian Brindley suggested

Comment: Does it work with `$uibModal` without adding `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the controller correctly

Instead of this

`app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    // ...
}`

use this

`app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    // ...
}]);`

Comment: Unfortunately this was just a copy&paste error as I removed the code inside `function()`